# Css Filter for Different Browsers

Tags: html, css, browser-support, css-filters

I have css which works for Web-Kit browsers (*case when alt-text is displayed*):

```
 .image { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(2) opacity(0.5);}
```

But i need support of other browsers like FireFox, Opera, IE8+

So i try to get expected result using next css updates:

```
 .image {       
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(2) opacity(0.5);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(2) opacity(0.5);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(2) opacity(0.5);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

For IE i don't think that i cover all css properties that are for web-kit.

But this doesn't work in Mozila and IE.

**Live Example : https://jsfiddle.net/fdf5kx5z/1/**

---

**UPDATE**

When i add just `opacity:0.5; color: #999999` then it become much more closer to what i expect.

Comment: If browser compatibility is an issue, you should open the image in an editor and apply those filters, then save it and use that image instead. `filter`s can be quite slow and should only really be used if you need dynamic filters.

Comment: this is for case when image is absent and alt-text is displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use code that is generated by CSS postprocessors:

```
.image { 
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="filter">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
    <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2" />
      <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2" />
      <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0.5" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    </svg>#filter'); 
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(2) opacity(0.5); 
   filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(2) opacity(0.5);
}
```

This was generated by [Pleeease!](http://pleeease.io/play/)